Retrieve the value of an object from it's key in mongoDB
I'm noob in mongoDB, you can find a mongoDB document example at the end.
I want to multiply the data.consumption by the value store in the object coef according the metadata.sensorId.
In the example the metadata.sensorId is "SENSOR_32", so the coef we want to multiply is 1.2.
The multiplied value would be stored as another new field "multiplied_consumption" for example.
How can i do it.
{
  "metadata": {
    "sensorId": "SENSOR_32"
  },
  "data": {
    "consumption": 3.547,
    "powerOutput": 21.282
  },
  "coef": {
    "SENSOR_32": 1.2,
    "SENSOR_33": 1.32,
    "SENSOR_34": 1.62,
    "SENSOR_35": 2.3,
    "SENSOR_36": 2.47,
    "SENSOR_37": 2.46,
    "SENSOR_38": 1.62
  }
}


The required coef can be found by converting the coef's to an array, and then getting the specific key where the sensor name matches the metadata.sensorId. This pipeline shows all the steps, giving a result of 4.2564 (1.2 * 3.547) for your example:
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { coef_arr: { $objectToArray: "$coef" } } },
  {
    $set: {
      reqd_coef: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$coef_arr",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$metadata.sensorId"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      multiplied_consumption: {
        $multiply: ["$reqd_coef.v", "$data.consumption"]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
And this pipeline makes it one step with a merge:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      multiplied_consumption: {
        $multiply: [
          {
            $getField: {
              field: "v",
              input: {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$coef" },
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$metadata.sensorId"] }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "$data.consumption"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $merge: "collection" }
])

Mongo Playground as a single step & merge
